# I wanted to add 3rd party badges in plain html table in Angular

Tags: html, jquery, css, typescript, angular12

So I have created custom table which allows me to have control over each cell(rowspan, colspan, css class,text to be shown) in Angular. In this table I have a column which has PASS or FAIL so I have  to show Badge there in the entire column. how do I show these badges in table. Any help is appreciated

the badges look like this
[kmd-badges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o5d9.png)

Comment: It is not bootstrap badge,but some 3rd party badges

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.